# OLEDB reads data's type wrongly from xls file in x64 windows?

Tags: c++, excel, 64-bit, oledb

my os is windows server 2012 r2 (x64) and installed with excel 2013 (x64), in my cpp code i'm reading an .xls file as:

```
#import "C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/msado15.dll"  rename("EOF", "adoEOF") rename("BOF", "adoBOF")

String ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\my_data.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
_bstr_t connStr = _bstr_t(ConnStr.c_str());

HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL); 

ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pCon;
pCon.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection));
pCon->Open(connStr, "", "", NULL);

String SqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [data_sheet$]";

ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRec;
pRec.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset)));
pRec->Open(_SqlStr.c_str(), connStr, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText);
```

So far so good, but then, when I read the cell's content by

```
_variant_t v = pRec->Fields->GetItem(0)->Value;
```

, an error happened: the field read in is actually a numeric data, but the data type `v.vt` shows `VT_BSTR` instead of `VT_R8`, which are defined in `wtypes.h` as:

```
enum VARENUM
{
    VT_EMPTY    = 0,
    VT_NULL = 1,
    ...
    VT_R8   = 5,
    ...
    VT_BSTR = 8,
```

, so a Double value is read in as a String -- `v.bstrVal` shows the double value in string, while `v.dblVal` shows something like `2.047048723726e-312#DEN`.

Anyone met this issue before, how could the data type be read in correctly?

Comment: Don't know C++ very well but I had similar situation in Java.  I will have to make a function to parse cell type first before reading into the program.  Take a look of this post (http://www.libxl.com/read-excel-data.html) and wish you luck.

Comment: yeah basically ms drivers did some guess and not always right.